# Reverse the words in Java with recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

```
public class PrintElements {

     public static void printReverse (String str)
        {
                if ((str==null)||(str.length() <= 1)) 
                   System.out.print(str); 
                else
                { 
                    System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length()-1));             
                    printReverse(str.substring(0,str.length()-1)); 
                }    
        }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="this function reverse";
        printReverse(str);

    }

}
```

In this method, I am trying to just change the place the words not letters place with using recursion.

For example, if `"this function reverse"` is the input, the output should be `"Reverse function this"`.

But my current output is : `"esrever noitcnuf siht"`

Comment: Use String.split() to put the words into an array, then reverse the array.

Comment: @GriffeyDog - Your idea was good but probably it was overwhelming for OP who doesn't seem to be so experienced. At the same time, I didn't want your idea to go waste. So, I've written [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101712/reverse-the-words-in-java-with-recursively/61102316#61102316) so that if someone is looking for a solution based on your idea, it can be useful.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void printReverse(String str) {
        if (str == null || !str.contains(" ")) {
            System.out.print(str);
            return;
        }
        String[] words = str.split("\\s+");// Split str on space(s)
        System.out.print(words[words.length - 1] + " ");// Print the last element

        // Call the method recursively by passing a new string with all but last word
        printReverse(String.join(" ", Arrays.asList(words).subList(0, words.length - 1)));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "this function reverse";
        printReverse(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
reverse function this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return "";
    if (!str.contains(" "))
        return str;

    int whitespacePos = str.indexOf(" ");
    String firstWord = str.substring(0, whitespacePos);
    return reverseString(str.substring(whitespacePos + 1)) + " " + firstWord;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "this function reverse";
    System.out.println(reverseString(str));
}
```

I tested this code and it works

1. It is (most of the time) cleaner to return a String, and then print this String if you want to.
2. If you use charAt(), you are only getting individual characters. Therefore it will be difficult to not also reverse the letters of the words. It is easier to find the whitespaces between the words and then to retrieve whole words with subString()
3. the subString() method can take two parameters, startIndex and endIndex, or just one parameter, only the startIndex. It then returns the subString from this startIndex up to the end of the String.

Note: I know you can use split(), I wanted to show how it can be done with indexes. If you already use split(), you might aswell not use recursion.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It traverses the input string and finds out each word and then merges them into the reversed string by reversing the order of the words.

```
public static void printReverse (String str)
{
    if ((str == null) || (str.equals(""))) 
       return ;
    str = str + " "; //to add a space at the end. this will help in detecting the last word
    String revStr = "", word = "";
    char c;
    for (int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
         c = str.charAt(0);
         if (c != ' ')
         {
             word = word + c;
         }
         else
         {
             revStr = word + " " + revStr;
         }
    }

    System.out.println(revStr.Trim()); //removes the extra space from the end

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I need recursive method. But thanks again

Comment: Oh okay. In that case, we can replace the for loop with a recursive call with an exit condition which checks the length of the original string and returns it when length == 0

I guess there are other correct answers already here.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void reverseWords(String str){
        if(str=="" || str==null){ 
            return;
        }else {
            String[] _str = str.split(" ");
            System.out.println(_str[_str.length-1]);
            String[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(_str,_str.length-1);
            reverseWords(String.join(" ", newArr));
        }
    }
```

dont forget to import

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseString(String str){
    if(str.lastIndexOf(32) ==-1){ //32 is an ASCII value for space 
        return str;
    }
    return str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(32)+1)+" "+reverseString(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(32)));

    //Here lastIndexOf() method get the last element of space so that method substring takes the String after last space because is used lastIndexOf(32)+1 and 
   //reverseString() method continuously takes up to n-1 from nth string until lastIndexOf() return -1 i.e no more whitespace avaliable 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```java
public String reverseString(final String str){
    //Using ternary operator
    return (str.lastIndexOf(32) == -1)
        ? str
        : str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(32) + 1) + " "  + reverseString(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(32)));
}
```

or with if-else:

```java
public String reverseString(final String str){
    if (str.lastIndexOf(32) == -1))
        return str;
    else
        return str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(32) + 1) + " "  + reverseString(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(32)));
}
```

`32` is the `space` character. So if there's no `space` in the string it just returns the string (word). If there is one it recursively swaps the tail after the  and the word before it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much ! It is helpful really